# First Rails project: Problem installing yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedora, yarnpkg

I am trying to get started with Rails, following the guide at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, but I'm running into problems.

I've got ruby, sqlite3, and rails installed as required, and then run

```
rails new blog
```

as indicated in section 3.2 of the tutorial. I get an error saying "Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.", but I can install the gems into `./vendor/bundle`, as suggested (I don't have full root access on this machine).

So far, so good. But then

```
rails webpacker:install
```

is run by the process, which gives me the following message:

```
Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
```

Of course, I went to that website and checked the instructions for my Fedora system and tried to follow them. The problem is again: I have limited root access, I cannot run the suggested commands; in particular, I cannot write to `/etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo`.

I also googled a bit, and what I could do is following https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/nodejs/nodejs.html to install Node.js and Yarn (including setting the alias `yarn` for `nodejs-yarn`). But still, running

```
rails webpacker:install
```

says that Yarn is not installed.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have to admit that I don't really know what I'm doing. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @martinn, You mention that you can't run the commands because you have limited root access. I'm wondering if you are familiar with using the `sudo` command, which is necessary sometimes to avoid running a command as root.

Comment: You should be able to use sudo providing the user is in the sudoers group. If not then maybe you can ask the system administrator to add it.

Comment: I installed and ran rails on many machines, and only once recently slip into the same problem. If you were able to install Homebrew and Rails, you have enough privileges to install yarn, so that may not be the problem. Try just to run a plain `yarn`, does it work? I got `uninitialized constant Socket::SOL_TCP (NameError)` and find out that there were conflicting versions of yarn, and after `gem uninstall yarn`, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux, the `sudo` command is the intended way to temporarily elevate user privledges.

```sh
wget https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

That should get Yarn installed for you. The other problem it seems your having is installing ruby gems. You should be able to write to the vendor directory of your application by default, so make sure that you're doing this project in your `/home/<MY USER NAME HERE>` directory.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I know the sudo command, and I used it for installing other stuff. It is somehow restricted by the admins, I can't do everything apparently (but i haven't found a pattern yet). I'll definitely check out the install scrip to see what this did.

Yarn is installed, but I'm running into other problems now. I'll give it a try myself now :)

Comment: Feel free to comment here if you have any more problems and I don't mind helping.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac

```
brew install yarn
```

then run `rails webpacker:install`